# ASP.NET MVC5 with StructureMap and OWIN auth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, structuremap, owin, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have inherited an application that uses Owin authentication and bootstraps like this (via the PreApplicationStartMethod attribute)

```
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30), regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });

            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
            app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
        }
    }
```

I have introduced StructureMap.MVC5 which works fine generally but not in the case of the `ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationSignInManager & ApplicationRoleManager.`  How can I resolve this so that the `Create` methods of these classes are called with `IOwinContext` and `IdentityFactoryOptions`.   I understand I need to bridge the Owin resolver somehow to structuremap but I'm unclear on exactly how?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am having the same issue and the StructureMap guys aren't too helpful

Comment: I did but I don't recall the details and I no longer have access to that code base.  I know someone who does though, I'll send this a link to this question, might be a while before he comes back due to time of year.